# How long before the AzCopy's Azure AD login expire?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I have a python script that runs daily and it needs to upload a file to Azure storage at a certain time every day.

I am trying to use the AzCopy commands to upload files to azure storage automatically. I plan to sign in AzCopy once and let it run and upload automatically for as long as it can.

I start with `azcopy login --tenant-id=<my tenant id>` and authenticate azcopy manually by going to the browser and entering the code.

I want to know how long can I keep it logged in before I need to reauthenticate azcopy again?

PS. I am not planning to run the command `azcopy logout` to log out manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but in such a case the better way is a non-interactive way e.g. use a service principal to login.

Log in as a service principal by using a client secret: Set the environment variable `AZCOPY_SPA_CLIENT_SECRET` to the client secret for secret based service principal auth.

```
azcopy login --service-principal --application-id <your service principal's application ID>
```

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-login#examples

**Update:**

The same as [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli), after using `azcopy login`, it will generate an `accessToken.json` file in your local path `~/.azcopy/`(Azure CLI is `~/.azure/`), it includes the Auzre AD [access token and refresh token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/security-tokens), when the access token was expired, azcopy will use the refresh token to get a new access token and a new refresh token. It means if your refresh token does not expires, it can always get the new access token. By default, this refresh token is revoked after **90** days of inactivity, for the specific value, it depends on the specific [token lifetime configuration in your AAD tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#refresh-and-session-token-lifetime-policy-properties).

So in conclusion, if you often use azcopy command before the refresh token expires, you can always keep logged in your account.

Comment: The problem is that I have a work account and it does not have permission to register app to generate application id and client secret etc. Neither do I have permission to generate SAS connection string so I need to figure out some other way to keep it signed in